# How to write code for IntelliJ - Android Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am writing a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA that depends on the Android plugin.

The IntelliJ Community Edition source code doesn't seem to include the Android plugin. I want to access the APIs  like `AndroidFacet` and `AndroidUtils` in my plugin project. How can I go about doing this? I tried pulling code from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/ and adding it to classpath but no luck so far.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The above might be confusing. What i really need is the JARs for the Android plugin so that I can add them to the ClassPath and access stuff  like AndroidFacet, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this manual [Developing IDEA plugin with dependency on Scala plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Developing+IDEA+plugin+with+dependency+on+Scala+plugin). Change Scala plugin with the android plugin.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I need. My question is about how to determine the dependencies the user has defined on the project _from within_ a custom plugin. Besides other things, in my plugin I need the classpath of the project